Camera Won't Shake When Enemy Attacked
I want my camera shake when isDamaging = true at EnemyDamage script but It wont happent
I dont even get why theres a problem with that stuff it doesnt make sense its looking like %100 true
when I printed the isDamaing its also says it =true but dont work
shake script:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class gotHit : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool start = false;
public AnimationCurve curve;
public float duration = 1f;
private EnemyDamage enemyDamage;
public Transform camera;
private Coroutine shakeCoroutine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        enemyDamage = GameObject.FindWithTag("ucgen").GetComponent<EnemyDamage>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (start)
        {
            start = false;
            Debug.Log("start ile sarsılma başlatılıyor.");
            StartShaking();
        }
    
        if (enemyDamage.isDamaging)
        {
            Debug.Log("enemyDamage.isDamaging ile sarsılma başlatılıyor.");
            StartShaking();
            enemyDamage.isDamaging = false; 
        }
    }
    
    void StartShaking()
    {
        if (shakeCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(shakeCoroutine);
        }
        shakeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(Shaking());
    }
    
    IEnumerator Shaking()
    {
        Vector3 startPosition = camera.position;
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
    
        while (elapsedTime < duration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            float strength = curve.Evaluate(elapsedTime / duration);
            camera.position = startPosition + Random.insideUnitSphere * strength; 
            yield return null;
        }
    
        camera.position = startPosition;
    }

}


Enemy damage script:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
public int enemyTriangleDamage = 2;
private PlayerHealth playerHealth;
public bool isDamaging = false; // Coroutine'in tekrar başlamasını engellemek için bayrak

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Oyuncu sağlığı bileşenini bulun
        GameObject player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        if (player != null)
        {
            playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        }
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("isDamaging durumu: " + isDamaging);
    }
    
    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision2D)
    {
        if (!isDamaging && collision2D.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Diee());
        }
    }
    
    IEnumerator Diee()
    {
        isDamaging = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        if (playerHealth != null)
        {
            playerHealth.TakeDamage(enemyTriangleDamage);
        }
        isDamaging = false;
    }

}

I tried ChatGpt too but it did not help me too.

I tried your code and it worked perfectly for me, so maybe you should try testing, whether you've set all of the variables correctly? Is the enemyDamage getting set? Did you select a curve? Did you set the camera variable to your camera? If so, then I have no idea why it wouldn't work for you. Sorry if the answer isn't that helpfull, but I can't think of any other reasons.

Since you are using tags, I would first triple check if they match. Since this is english site, it would be very helpful to translate your comments and logs into english as well. Also you did not say if the error is in shake effect or activating it (Does effect even work). Please edit the post so you tell where is the problem.
